# Instantiation exception in Java code for Android app

Tags: java, javascript, android, cordova

I have written the code for fetching current page from the carrousel slider Image in HTML and share it via email and MMS using Java in Android for phonegap project.

This is my Java code:

```
public class Share extends CordovaPlugin {


private FileOutputStream outStream; 
private File file;
Bitmap bm;
public static final String ACTION_POSITION = "ShareImage";
Context context;
public Share(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext)
        throws JSONException {

    if (ACTION_POSITION.equals(action)) {

        try {
            JSONObject arg_object = args.getJSONObject(0);
            Intent sendIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.setType("image/jpg");
            String uri = "@drawable/"+arg_object.getString("image")+".jpg";
            int imageResource = context.getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, context.getPackageName());
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource( context.getResources(), imageResource);
            String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            file = new File(extStorageDirectory, "image.png");
                try {
                outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
                outStream.flush();
                outStream.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
            sendIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, arg_object.getString("image"));
            this.cordova.getActivity().startActivity(sendIntent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
                callbackContext.error(e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

Everything goes fine, but when I clicked the "share" button I get the exception as "Class not found". 
The issue is in context class, tried by cleaning and deleted the gen file as given in the Google, but nothing worked out. Please help me to fix this.

Logcat output:

```
11-09 20:30:44.156: W/System.err(2842): java.lang.InstantiationException: com.picsswipe.Share
  11-09 20:30:44.156: W/System.err(2842):   at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
 11-09 20:30:44.156: W/System.err(2842):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
 11-09 20:30:44.156: W/System.err(2842):    at org.apache.cordova.api.PluginEntry.createPlugin(PluginEntry.java:80)
 11-09 20:30:44.164: W/System.err(2842):    at org.apache.cordova.api.PluginManager.getPlugin(PluginManager.java:249)
 11-09 20:30:44.164: W/System.err(2842):    at org.apache.cordova.api.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:206)
 11-09 20:30:44.164: W/System.err(2842):    at org.apache.cordova.ExposedJsApi.exec(ExposedJsApi.java:51)
11-09 20:30:44.164: W/System.err(2842):     at android.webkit.WebViewCore.nativeHandleTouchEvent(Native Method)
11-09 20:30:44.164: W/System.err(2842):     at android.webkit.WebViewCore.nativeHandleTouchEvent(Native Method)
 11-09 20:30:44.164: W/System.err(2842):    at android.webkit.WebViewCore.access$6200(WebViewCore.java:54)
 11-09 20:30:44.164: W/System.err(2842):    at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub$1.handleMessage(WebViewCore.java:1658)
 11-09 20:30:44.164: W/System.err(2842):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 11-09 20:30:44.164: W/System.err(2842):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
11-09 20:30:44.164: W/System.err(2842):     at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:685)
 11-09 20:30:44.164: W/System.err(2842):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

`share.js` plugin:

```
  var Share = function() {};

Share.prototype.show = function(success, fail, path) {
    return cordova.exec( function(args) {
        success(args);
    }, function(args) {
        fail(args);
    }, 'Share', 'ShareImage', [{"image": path}]);
};

if(!window.plugins) {
    window.plugins = {};
}
if (!window.plugins.share) {
    window.plugins.share = new Share();
}
```

`config.xml`:

```
 <feature name="Share">
  <param name="android-package" value="com.picsswipe.Share"/>
  </feature>
```

Comment: Have you defined the plugin class name in the xml that is generated by phonegap plugin in xml folder.

Comment: yes i have defined config.xml file @nikhil.thakkar

Comment: Can you please paste your complete class file and config.xml?

Comment: yes updated, please see my question @nikhil.thakkar

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
       Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
       or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
       distributed with this work for additional information
       regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
       to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
       "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
       with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

         http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

       Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
       software distributed under the License is distributed on an
       "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
       KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
       specific language governing permissions and limitations
       under the License.
-->
<cordova>
    <!--
    access elements control the Android whitelist.
    Domains are assumed blocked unless set otherwise
     -->

    <access origin="http://127.0.0.1*"/> <!-- allow local pages -->

    <!-- <access origin="https://example.com" /> allow any secure requests to example.com -->
    <!-- <access origin="https://example.com" subdomains="true" /> such as above, but including subdomains, such as www -->
    <access origin=".*"/>

    <!-- <content src="http://mysite.com/myapp.html" /> for external pages -->
    <content src="home.html" />

    <log level="DEBUG"/>
    <preference name="useBrowserHistory" value="true" />
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
<plugins>
    <plugin name="App" value="org.apache.cordova.App"/>
    <plugin name="Geolocation" value="org.apache.cordova.GeoBroker"/>
    <plugin name="Device" value="org.apache.cordova.Device"/>
    <plugin name="Accelerometer" value="org.apache.cordova.AccelListener"/>
    <plugin name="Compass" value="org.apache.cordova.CompassListener"/>
    <plugin name="Media" value="org.apache.cordova.AudioHandler"/>
    <plugin name="Camera" value="org.apache.cordova.CameraLauncher"/>
    <plugin name="Contacts" value="org.apache.cordova.ContactManager"/>
    <plugin name="File" value="org.apache.cordova.FileUtils"/>
    <plugin name="NetworkStatus" value="org.apache.cordova.NetworkManager"/>
    <plugin name="Notification" value="org.apache.cordova.Notification"/>
    <plugin name="Storage" value="org.apache.cordova.Storage"/>
    <plugin name="FileTransfer" value="org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer"/>
    <plugin name="Capture" value="org.apache.cordova.Capture"/>
    <plugin name="Battery" value="org.apache.cordova.BatteryListener"/>
    <plugin name="SplashScreen" value="org.apache.cordova.SplashScreen"/>
    <plugin name="Echo" value="org.apache.cordova.Echo" />
    <plugin name="Globalization" value="org.apache.cordova.Globalization"/>
    <plugin name="InAppBrowser" value="org.apache.cordova.InAppBrowser"/>
    <plugin name="SQLitePlugin" value="com.phonegap.plugin.sqlitePlugin.SQLitePlugin"/>
    <plugin name="Sync" value="com.phonegap.plugin.syncPlugin.SyncDB" />
</plugins>
</cordova>
```

This is the default config.xml which I have.
You need to specify the plugin name and the class name in the value attribute as is shown in the above xml.

Kindly refer to the following link http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html

In case of help let me know.

Comment: So yours will be
   <plugin name="Share" value="your fully qualified class name" />